# How to set the public path on angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

So I need to configure the public folder of my application, in other words, 
I want the assets to point to my own path on the generated index file 
like src="mypublicpath/assets/app.js"

I'm really sure this is a value that needs to be set on the angular-cli.json configuration.

this is my file

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "name": "ng-app-manager"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../bundles/ng-app-manager",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

I just need the equivalent to webpacks "publicPath"

Comment: if you are using angular cli `v1.0.0` you can `eject` your app and change the webpack config. eject doc: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `deployUrl` option in [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli). Your `angular-cli.json` would look like this.

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "name": "ng-app-manager"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "..\/bundles\/ng-app-manager",
      "deployUrl": "http://my.cdn.host.com/assets",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [

      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments\/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments\/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments\/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": ".\/protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src\/**\/*.ts",
      "project": "src\/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e\/**\/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e\/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": ".\/karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

Running `ng build` will then automatically prefix resource references in the `dist` folder, with `http://my.cdn.host.com/assets`. For example, the reference for `app.js` will into `http://my.cdn.host.com/assets/app.js`.