# Change the base URL of compiled font files in Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, configuration, webpack, compilation, font-awesome

I'm a little new to Angular so hopefully what I'm having issues with is possible to fix.

In my Angular project, when we run `ng build` we compile the source into a specific desination directory in our webapp folder called **ng**. We're including some modules that need to use some fontawesome and roboto-v15 font files so it appears to copy the required font files over to the **ng** directory (The files are named like **fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8.woff2** and **fontawesome-webfont.b06871f281fee6b241d6.ttf**).

On the pages where we include the angular module it tries to request these files using the Base URL of the page we're currently on, when in reality I need it to look in the **ng** directory instead

For example when I load up the page I get these 404 errors in the console:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/test/url/roboto-v15-latin-regular.7e367be02cd17a96d513.woff2.
```

I need to configure the angular compiler to tell it that these files are instead located at `http://localhost:8080/ng/roboto-v15-latin-regular.7e367be02cd17a96d513.woff2`.

When I take a look at the compiled **styles.bundle.js** I can find references to the resource files it's putting into the style on the page. Here's what that looks like:

```
/***/ "../../../../primeng/resources/themes/omega/fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.woff":
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

module.exports = __webpack_require__.p + "roboto-v15-latin-regular.16e1d930cf13fb7a9563.woff";

/***/ }),
```

If I could figure out what config setting can set the **__webpack_require__.p** variable to **ng/** then it would be perfect. At the moment I'm manually importing these font files on the page itself, but I have a feeling this is going to be a problem if I ever want to use other modules that happen to compile some resource files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I've realized my question was kind of poorly phrased. I found the answer to what I was looking for here:

[How to set the public path on angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497322/how-to-set-the-public-path-on-angular-4)

The setting I was looking for was to try and set the public path for my resource files. This setting is controlled by the **deployUrl** parameter in **.angular-cli.json**